# Sidebar addon display - any way to make is faster?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a sidebar add-on on a google sheet.
The display time is rather slow (about 7 seconds from triggering the sidebar display to the refresh.

I tried with a very simple server side script function below (just return a dummy value) and it still takes the same amount of time to display (so the problem is not the complexity of the function server-side).

Is there anything that can be done to speed it up ?

code.gs

```
function onOpen(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Show sidebar", functionName: "showSidebar"}]; 
  ss.addMenu("TestMenu", menuEntries);
}


function getDataDummy() {
  return {data: "foo"};
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('TestSidebar')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle("Title");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

TestSidebar.html

```
<div class="sidebar branding-below">
  <p>
  Test
  </p>
  <div class="block div-table" id="sidebar-record-block">
  <div id="field-data" class="div-table-row"><div class="div-table-td"><input type=text id="data" /></div></div>  
  </div>
  <div class="block" id="sidebar-button-bar">
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar-status"></div>
</div>

<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('TestSidebar.javascript').getContent(); ?>
```

TestSidebar.javascript

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getDataDummy();
  });

  function showData(record) {
    if (record && record["data"]) {
      $("#data").val(record["data"]);
    }
  }
</script>
```

This code doesn't do anything with the sheet itself, but from click on the menu to the data being displayed, it takes 7s.

Comment: Try putting all html/js in the same file

Comment: The callback execution time in your sidebar to show the HTML depends on your network speed as well. Are you experiencing any problem with your internet connection? It loads in about 2 seconds in my test.

Comment: I am in France - on a mobile connection (latency not so bad, but certainly not as good as fiber connection).

Comment: Do you have any browser extension that reads your page contents or requests? Try to disable any potential candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getDataDummy() {
  return {data: "foo"};
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html='<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script></head>';
  html+='<body><div class="sidebar branding-below"><p>Test</p><div class="block div-table" id="sidebar-record-block">';
  html+='<div id="field-data" class="div-table-row"><div class="div-table-td"><input type=text id="data" /></div></div>';
  html+='</div><div class="block" id="sidebar-button-bar"></div><div id="sidebar-status"></div></div>';
  html+='<script>$(function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getDataDummy();});function showData(record) {if(record && record["data"]){$("#data").val(record["data"]);}}</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle('No Title'));
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, and still same time (8s now). I will try various connection speeds (the lockdown might have an impact). I am in France btw, that could have an impact on the latency